# Laravel - insert data with joined tables

Tags: php, laravel, database, backend

[image]based on my database , i want users to be able to post cases through a form that contains (casetypeid with some other field) but my case table only contains the casetypeid because i have a separate table for case type. so how can users write the case type and based on the name the correct id gets inserted in the case table?

here is what i have tried so far :

```
 public function createcase(){
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'caseTypeId' => 'required',
            'uid' => 'required',

        ]);
        case::create($request->post());
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'waiting donation successfull',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem here ? it looks like you are posting the good data. Is `caseTypeId` fillable in your model ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux when users fill the table, they dont know the caseTypeId instead they just know the case type. so if users write the case type (education) and in the case type table education has id of 1, then  i want 1 to be inserted in the caseTypeId in the case table.

Comment: Check `firstOrCreate` eloquent's method. before creating the case, you would create or fetch existing case type.